# Configuring password reuse policy and password strength while using Firebase as authentication provider

Tags: firebase-authentication

My app is using Firebase as authentication provider. It has a feature to login using google account or create an anonymous credential having an email and password combination. To create a new user with anonymous credential I am making a to  'createUserWithEmailAndPassword' function. Is there any way, without a code change,  where I can set password strength and prohibit already used password for a user who tries to reset the password.

Answer (score 0):

> or create an anonymous credential having an email and password combination.

The [Firebase Anonymous Authentication](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/anonymous-auth) is quite different than the [Email and Password Authentication](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/password-auth) . The first one doesn't require any data from the user, while the second one requires an email address and a password.

> I am making a to 'createUserWithEmailAndPassword' function. Is there any way, without a code change, where I can set password strength and prohibit already used passwords for a user who tries to reset the password?

No, there is nothing built-in. As the [docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/password-auth#sign_in_a_user_with_an_email_address_and_password) say:

> When a new user signs up using your app's sign-up form, complete any new account validation steps that your app requires, such as verifying that the new account's password was correctly typed and meets your complexity requirements.

You have to make sure that the password has a specific length, is correctly typed and meets your complexity requirements.